# Is it possible to use an assumption that a parameter is an odd or even number?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I am trying to integrate:

```
Integrate[(Exp[x]*(x^m)/((Exp[x] + 1)^2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I know that for odd m the result is zero. How can I tell Mathematica that `m` is odd? Using `Assumptions` maybe?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please format your posts in the future. Formatting instructions are displayed on the right of the edit box.

Comment: Yes, `Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers && Mod[m, 2] == 1`

Comment: I'm curious for general forumla if `m` is even?

Comment: The same but the modulus must be set equal to zero.

Comment: But Mathematica can't find solution ?

Comment: Mathematica cannot find a general solution. For m=2 the integral is $\pi^{2} /3$, for $m=4$ ,$7\pi^{4}/15$, etc.

Comment: Thank you Edmund! If you like, write your comment as an aswer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrand is symmetric in x for odd m. Therefore integral must be zero. Write 2*m+1 (Element [m,Integers]) for odd integers.

```
integrand[x_] = (Exp[x]*(x^(2 m + 1))/((Exp[x] + 1)^2));

integrand[x] == -integrand[-x] // 
   FullSimplify[#, x \[Element] Reals && m \[Element] Integers] &

(*   True   *)
```

**Edit**

For even m, integral can be found with integer search engines from http://oeis.org/

```
(*    Integrate[(Exp[x]*(x^(2 m))/((Exp[x] + 1)^2)), 
                     {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] 
== (-2 + 4^m) Abs[BernoulliB[2 m]]*Pi^(2 m)    *)

tab = Table[
   Integrate[integrand[x, j], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], {j, 1, 
  20}];

tab2 = Table[(-2 + 4^m) Abs[BernoulliB[2 m]]*Pi^(2 m), {m, 1, 20}]

tab == tab2

(*  True    *)
```